# CSS Background URL not working in iOS (Chrome and Safari) fine on desktop

Tags: ios, css

I'm finding that the CSS below works as expected in desktop environments, but in iOS mobile environments, the image does not load at the background.

I've heard that fixed may not be workable in iOS environments, but I've also tested scroll - as well as multiple image sizes.

Thanks in advance

```
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: url(http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/web03/2011/11/11/16/enhanced-buzz-22138-1321048705-11.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `background` into `background-image`.

Comment: Nope, didn't do it! sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues:

1. Fixed was not supported on all mobile browsers and call the background image to fail to load.
2. I found that (on the contrary to caniuse.com) the background shorthand wasn't working in all browsers.

Working code:

```
.intro {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 100px 0;
text-align: center;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/web03/2011/11/11/16/enhanced-buzz-22138-1321048705-11.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```